# Strange behavior of isosurface() in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I build a 3D array using the following command:

```
test = zeros(100,100,100, 'uint8');
test(20,20,:) = 255;
```

then I called:

```
isosurface(test);
isosurface(test, 255);
```

Both shows nothing in the poped-up axes:
[image: isosurface 255].

However, using

```
isosurface(test,0)
```

shows the following result:
[image: isosurface 0].

According to my understand, calling `isosurface(test, 255)` should have the same effect as `isosurface(test,0)`. Why are they different here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isosurface uses interpolation, using `255` your surface has the size 0 and is not displayed.

For example (19.5,19.5,1) is included if you set isosurface to 0, but not if you set it to 255

```
>> interp3(test,19.5,19.5,1)

ans =

   64
```

Comment: I thought `isosurface` would generate a surface by connecting those locations whose values are 255, by specifying 255 as the second argument to it.

Comment: No, it fills everything which has a (interpolated) value above isovalue.